# Блок питания

Tags: пк

Как сделать, чтобы вместо стандартного блока питания на ПК прикрепить блок питания от ноутбука или подобный.

Comment: Вариант с паяльником рассматривается?

Comment: Принимаются все варианты! А что есть предложение? Я с удовольствием выслушаю!

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Для стандартного ПК такого нет. Есть для Mini-itx платформы переходник от адаптера, его найти в просторах интернета не сложно.

Comment: Тоесть какую мать мне нужно взять (конкретно) чтобы можно было подключать блок питание такого типа? Мать с каким сокетом?

Comment: Еще раз поясняю ТОЛЬКО подобные матери http://www.mini-itx.ru/shop/index.php?categoryID=4 и ТОЛЬКО подобные БП http://www.mini-itx.ru/shop/index.php?categoryID=454 . В стационарном ПК такое работать НЕ БУДЕТ.

Comment: Как в этом случае выглядит и работает блок питания?!

Answer (score 0):

Есть блоки питания для компьютеров, которые работают не от сети 220 вольт, а от 12 или 24 вольт постоянного тока. Вот такой, например: [mini-box M4-ATX автомобильный (6-30V) 250W](http://www.dont.ru/mini-box-M4-ATX-avtomobilnyj-(6-30V)-250W-p/n:112997.id13127.html). Оно?

Answer (score 0):

Если хорошо разбираешься в радиотехнике, то теоретически можно взять БП от ноута или подобный, потом через инверторы и схемы стабилизации выводить на нужные выводы (которые подключаются к материнской плате и другие (молекс, сата питание и т.п...)). Но это нужно очень хорошо в этом разбираться, чтоб не спалить какую нибудь часть компа повышеным током.